# How to say "I thought you are..." to a response?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Let's start with an example:

> A: 你是学生吗？
>
> B: 不是，我是老师。
>
> C: I thought you are student!

<sub>Note that C is a different person from A.</sub>

In this case, how can I say "I thought..."?

I know in Mandarin, you usually use an adverb or an adverbial phrase to express the past tense (e.g. 以前), but in this case, I don't know how I should express the past tense. At least I feel it is awkward to say 以前我认为你是学生.

Or maybe I should add 过 to say 我认为过你是学生, but I'm not sure and still feel a bit awkward...

If I say 我认为你是学生, I feel like the person C thinks the person B is lying and is actually a student. This may lead to the misunderstanding, I think.

So how should I express the past tense in these cases?

Comment: It is "我还以为你是学生"

Comment: @TangHo Does it not mean "I still think you are a student."? Anyway don't hesitate to write it as an answer, thanks.

Comment: 以为 w/o any 动态助词 like 过，see dictionary examples (e.g. bkrs) for 以为: 人们以为我迷路了。 People thought I had lost my way，我以为你是学生 also see previous comparison of
认为／以为

Comment: @user6065 Ah you are right, in Pleco the example sentence has: 我还以为是她呢。 means "I had thought it was her.". But then why is 还 needed here? Looking up the entry for 还 doesn't get me anything related to the past tense usage...

Comment: it seems 还 is used to make the statement clearer, more unmistakable, users might look at previous discussions of
all the meanings and uses of 还

Comment: it could correspond to "and I thought",see Webster's dictionary:  and 2a—used as a function word to express logical modification, consequence, antithesis, or supplementary explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "我还以为你是学生"

认为 (consider; think) can be in any tense

but 以为 already mean "(previously) thought"

[还](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/815/) is a common adverb with many meanings. In this case, it means 'even'

还以为 = '(even) thought'

Comment: Thanks. In this case if I add the past particle such as 过 or 了, is it grammatically wrong? Or what kind of impressions does it make?

Comment: 还以为过 sounds awkward because 以为 already indicated 'previously thought' . 过  or 了 is redundant.

Comment: 过 or 了 is usually used with some **procedural** verb like 我吃过了, while '以为' (thought ... [which reveals to be wrong]) indicates a lasting **situation**. So that's another reason why 过 or 了 sounds not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

You need the subjunctive 'were' for this sentence in English, because the apparent state is not real, or you would not have said this.

I thought you were a student.
我本来以为你是个学生。

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic ways in this situation:

1. 我(还)以为你是学生呢！
2. 之前，我还以为你是学生呢！

还 can be omitted. If you want to put an exclamation mark at the end, you'd better add 呢.